# Can I leverage Windows authentication to use my private GPG key?

Tags: windows, authentication, windows-authentication, gpg4win

I have a private GPG key and a virtual desktop running Windows (VDI) I do development on. I have to authenticate to connect to the VDI and I am logged into the VDI as my own user. I can securely transfer my private key to the VDI, but this still requires entering the password for the GPG key at least once (up to caching) in order to use it. The VDI reboots every time I disconnect, so caching lasts only up to a day. (I’m trying to design a process for the entire team to use – having this duplicated authentication will be seen as a regression and is going to be a hard sell. The only alternative on the table is home-grown authentication – obviously not ideal.)

Can I leverage the Windows authentication to ‘pass through’ the GPG authentication?

I would be perfectly satisfied to have the password of my GPG key need to be the same as my Windows password. If there isn’t some tool that already does this, I’m sure I could devise a process with which to keep the two in sync. Frankly, I just don’t know what I’m doing with Windows authentication methods and don’t know where to start. I would have expected some roughly-out-of-the-box solution for this, but I suspect I’m not using the right language in my searches.

Comment: Load the key into [Gpg4Win](https://www.gpg4win.org/) and you can configure the cache time via Kleopatra

Comment: @JW0914 As I indicated, any cache time I configure is meaningless if the VDI is regularly rebooting. AFAIK, the cache only takes effect after the first time you provide a passphrase. Thanks though!

Comment: A hardware key should [in theory] allow authentication to the VDI without re-entering a passphrase more than once if using RDP to pass through the USB port the hardware key is plugged into. Do you have a hardware key to test, such as a a [YubiKey](https://www.yubico.com/), as the hardware key would be unlocked once via [PIV Manager](https://developers.yubico.com/yubikey-piv-manager/), with Kleopatra running, and then can be used for however long its cache is set in Kleopatra provided PIV Manager is running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would be perfectly satisfied to have the password of my GPG key need to be the same as my Windows password. If there isn’t some tool that already does this,

No, that wouldn't be very useful. Windows does not give GPG or other (normal) software *any* access to your login password. In fact most places would consider it to be a major security hole if a program had access to the login credentials remembered by Windows (see e.g. the need for Credential Guard).

Passwords used by apps should be independent and only stored through the Credential Manager API, or encrypted using DPAPI, or at least in an EFS-encrypted file (in all three cases the encryption key is protected by your login password). Though, a downside is that any app, not just GPG, can access them.

The GPG *pinentry* app (the one which displays password popups) has, at least on Linux, the ability to save passwords in the OS credential manager (i.e. libsecret). If you're using Gpg4Win or something like that, it would be a sensible feature request to add similar functionality to the Windows version of *pinentry*.

(It would be possible to write your own pinentry, such as this [pinentry-wsl-ps1](https://github.com/diablodale/pinentry-wsl-ps1).)

---

Somewhat more secure would be to pass through the signing/decryption requests to a private key that's still stored on your local machine (similar to how ssh-agent works). Over Remote Desktop, this is natively possible and indeed almost completely transparent with smartcards and software using the Windows cryptographic API (CAPI and CNG).

The downside is, you do need a smartcard for this to work. For example, a Yubikey NEO connected locally *might* be detected by GPG's *scdaemon* on the remote end.

Comment: A Yubikey can authenticate a Windows session and provide a PGP key.  This is possible by putting two keys on the same device.  That’s probably the best you will be able to do given the limitations you have indicated

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't want Windows to surrender the login password in any way, shape, or form -- I was hoping for some mechanism by which GPG could ask Windows to decrypt something using the login credentials (unless this in itself would be a security hole! that would be news to me). Regarding Credential Manager / etc., would it be sensible to have a passwordless private key that is encrypted via these means? This is something I can bring up internally as well, but do you think that has a snowball's chance of being secure?

Comment: As I understand it, a password-protected private key in GPG-land is essentially that: a private key stored as a normal file that is decrypted using a password.

Comment: Usually, yes, that's exactly what it is. (Its fundamentally not too different from SSH id_rsa or TLS privkey.pem files.) Whether using CredMan to store the passphrase or EFS to encrypt gnupg's private-keys.d folder is considered *secure enough* depends situation... In your case, if someone can log into the VDI with your password they'd be able to read the gpg passphrase from CredMan – but they *also* would be able to replace the whole gpg with a malicious version that sends your manually typed password elsewhere. So it's not much of a difference.

Comment: Storing the key on a smartcard though (instead of a file) would be a major security improvement, and in some places even considered mandatory. It depends on what the key does, e.g. Git commit signatures aren't nearly as important as released software signatures.